# jQuery: lose focus on the element

Tags: jquery

Need to somehow lose focus on `<select>` after the `<option>` has been selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/MnAdN/

Without removing this focus check.

```
if (... !$('#adm1n-toolbar form select').is(':focus'))
```

Toolbar should be visible while user is doing selection, and should be hidden when selection is done.

Thanks.

Comment: How about setting the focus on another element that has no focus events?

Comment: Your fiddle contains the following selector which does not exist: `$('#adm1n-toolbar-content select')`

Comment: Yep.. But it exists in my original script. =)) I should drink less... (or more) ... =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `blur()` method, like this:

```
$("#adm1n-toolbar form select").change(function() {
    $(this).blur();
}); // after something has been selected
```

Comment: Are you calling it after something has been selected from your menu? Let me see if I can whip something like that up for you.

Comment: I thought .change() is something that is called when selection is done?

Comment: Yep. That's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @Radio It doesn't work because your selector is wrong. `#adm1n-toolbar-content select` returns no elements.

Comment: .blur() is the way to go. =)) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Trigger a blur event:

```
$('#yourSelect').blur();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just force the focus off the toolbar:

```
$('#adm1n-toolbar select').trigger('blur');
```

Using your jsFiddle:

```
$('#adm1n-toolbar')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top < 0) {
            $(this).animate({top: '0'}, 300);
        }
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top >= 0 && !$('#adm1n-toolbar form select').is(':focus')) {
            $(this).animate({top: '-115'}, 300);
        }
    });

$('#adm1n-toolbar select').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

​